# how to make div image width fullscreen but let the height go beyond the screen

Tags: html, css

[an overview picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSQCA.jpg)

hello everyone, i checked almost all of the solutions but i couldn't make it to work since i really new in this.
as you can see in the picture, i want my div background image as wide as the fullscreen, but i don't want the height to be cut by the screen sizes, i want it to be still scrollable down. i hope the picture is understanable enough and i hope you guys have a little time to help me, thanks a lot in advance!

edit: [that](https://horizon-demo.squarespace.com/) is the exact effect i'm looking for.

edit2: what i could do so far (i don't want to give the height a specific number, i want it to adapt naturally to the different screen sizes, and i can't know how high it will be for every screen, i gave it 1300 height which is ok for my laptop, but on my phone, oh god it's a mess):

```css
   #my_section_id_1 {
    background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/bv60Q0Z.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-size:100% auto;
    height: 1300px;
    }
```

```html
<section id="my_section_id_1">
<h1>my_section_id_1_content</h1>
</section>
<section id="my_section_id_2">
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must **include the shortest code** necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show us what you have tried and we will try to help you!

Comment: Rafael, thank you for your comment, i added an edit to my post now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `height` of a HTML element to a certain amount that is larger than screen height.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but for example, when i add "1300px" height to the post, on my laptop it looks a bit ok, but on mobile, or when i resize the screen, 1300px is Huge.. i want the height automatically adapt..

Answer (score 0):

You can put the img width to 100% :

```
img {
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

but I would rather suggest to add a background to a section and set a background image on it, so you can add more sections on the bottom of that without the background image to be affected by the scroll.

```
section {
background-image:url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-size:100% auto;
height: 200px;
}
```

```css
    #my_section_id_1 {
    background-image:url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-size:100% auto;
    height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<section id="my_section_id_1">
<h1>my_section_id_1_content</h1>
</section>
<section id="my_section_id_2">
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i don't want my image's height to be limited to 200 px or anything, my background image is something like 2000px wide and 1000 high, but different screen sizes will squeeze the width and i want the height to naturally adapt to the ratio automatically. exactly like i showed in the example link.

Comment: @todguzel then just put height to "auto", that's it. If you want the image scroll with the text, then you should use a "fixed" background-position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<div class="bg"></div>
```

And  this css:

```
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url("http://www.lorempixel.com/800/800");
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /*Avoid the image to repeat*/
  background-size: cover; /*Make the image full size*/
  background-position:center; /*Center the img*/
}
```

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/jycr5vzx/2/).

```css
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url("http://www.lorempixel.com/800/800");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>


<!-- To make the page scrollable -->
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
<p>Stuffs..</p>
```

Comment: you see, the image is full screen UNTIL scroll, [as i took a screenshot here](http://imgur.com/uHZsPjh), i want to be able to see the rest of the image by also scrolling down, AND then the content.